# Do Heroku Dynos enjoy free data transfer inside the AWS network?

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm considering using Heroku for a NodeJS app, and I was wondering if their Dynos enjoy the free internal data transfer inside the AWS network.

I want to use DynamoDB, ElastiCache, RDS, SQS and a bunch of other AWS offerings - if I can connect to all of them from Heroku, which region and AZ do I need to set them up in to talk to them for free from the Heroku Dynos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku runs in US-East region so as long as you setup there you shouldn't incur any transfer costs between dynos and other services.

There's more details on the https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon_rds page - it relates to RDS but a lot of it is general Amazon stuff like security groups etc.

Comment: Some additional security info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/external-services