# Can I use DynamoDB through Heroku?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-dynamodb

I am interested in using DynamoDB through Heroku. Will this work securely and how would I set up communication? I am using Java but help in any language would be fine.

Sources of info I've found thus far:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241184/do-heroku-dynos-enjoy-free-data-transfer-inside-the-aws-network) seems to imply it is possible without explaining how.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042794/can-i-use-amazon-elasticache-on-heroku) explains how Heroku can connect to elasticache (not DynamoDB) but goes on to explain that it is insecure as any Heroku application can connect to the elasticache server. I would like to make sure that however I connect to DynamoDB is, in fact, secure.
- [This video](http://lanyrd.com/2012/cloudstock/sqgxt/) explaining how to connect to DynamoDB via Ruby in Heroku is no longer available.
- [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjhhMpEGF2Y) keeps talking about how they're going to use DynamoDB from Heroku, and then the next presenter admits that he couldn't get something else to work and never went on to talk about using DynamoDB in Heroku.

Comment: Have you looked at Heroku's integration with MongoLab? https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. You can indeed use DynamoDB with Heroku. I use it for a large application that handles about 15 billion requests per month.

Here's what you'll want to do:

1. Set your `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables in your Heroku app. When you sign up for AWS, you'll have to generate these if you have none already. Once you get them, store them in Heroku as environment variables.
2. Install a DynamoDB library in your language / framework of choice.
3. When you initialize your AWS library for DynamoDB, it will ask for 2 things: your `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, so you can supply those from your environment variables.

The way this works in terms of security is like so:

- Heroku runs on AWS in the us-east region.
- If you create a DynamoDB instance in us-east, it will be in the same 'network' as your Heroku app.
- When your Heroku app connects to DynamoDB, it will do so securely over SSL, using your AWS API keys as a username/password to connect.
- When your Heroku app makes requests to DynamoDB, it will be very fast, as both your Heroku app and your DynamoDB instance are very close together physically.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Mind if I hijack this for clarification? I had the same question as OP, and just to make sure I understand your answer 100%, you're saying that a web app on Heroku and a DynamoDB service on AWS can talk to each other without using an HTTP intermediary web app (or API Gateway etc), as long as they're on the same AWS region.

So from the perspective of the Heroku app, there's DynamoDB running on localhost there? And when you try to get your library to connect to DynamoDB, it will just find it on localhost as long as you've got the AWS credentials set up in environment variables?

Comment: No. Not quite. What happens is that your Heroku app and your Dynamo instance are in the same AWS region, and this means you have very fast network connections to Dynamo from your Heroku server. It won't show up on local host, but you can use environment variables to store your Dynamo creds on heroku to make connecting to it painless.

Comment: Gotcha. I even tried this out today both connecting to AWS from a Heroku free dyno and from my local dev environment. Both worked! I can see now that you can connect to AWS from anywhere, it's just that Heroku being on the same region gives it an opportunity to be a blazing fast connection. Now I can create things that are hosted on Heroku for free and get 25 GB of NoSQL storage on DynamoDB, all for free. :) Very neat stuff.

Comment: Yep! Exactly :)